# Android crashes on keyboard plugging

Tags: android, exception, keyboard

I'm developing an Android application in which I need support a USB keyboard. I haven't developed something to explicitly support the USB keyboard because I thought that every application can use a USB keyboard.

The problem is that when I'm trying to connect or disconnect a USB keyboard, my application crashes without an error trace from the application.

My device is a Lenovo with Android 4.1 installed. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: A stacktrace would be nice...

Comment: There should be something in the `LogCat` window, go check it out and paste is here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An Activity configuration change occurs when the external keyboard is attached.

To resolve the crash, add the following element to the `AndroidManifest.xml` for all activities:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config), `android:configChanges`:

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When
>   a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down
>   and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the
>   activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is
>   called.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" to configChanges would still call onDestroy and onCreate of the activity. After a long research I found this article:
https://developer.samsung.com/sdp/blog/en-us/2017/12/07/samsung-dex-lifecycle-on-switching-between-mobile-and-samsung-dex-mode

Basically, if you use Lenovo's productivity mode or Samsung DeX, it would recreate the app nonetheless, so it's necessary to add all of these if you want for the app to not recreate itself when you add a physical keyboard.:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|density">
```

Also, add this for Samsung DeX inside your AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.samsung.android.keepalive.density" 
android:value="true" />
```