# Pluging Keyboard in crashes app (Xamarin.Forms, Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, keyboard

I essentially have the Issue from this 2014 Question. [Android crashes on keyboard plugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444476/android-crashes-on-keyboard-plugging)

In short: pluging in or disconnecting a physical keyboard (USB/Samsung POGO-Pins/USB) leads to the recreation of the activity due to the configchange.

I have the following issue: the proposed fix from the mentioned issue does not work. I added the following to my MainActivity:

`ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden`

No change in behaviour. Since the "crash" is not catchable it is hard do construct a workaround. I'll happily provide more infos, although the behaviour is identical in a clean project.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did this happened on all the kind of devices or only on some special devices?

Comment: I have observed this happening on SM-T545, SM-T510 and a random Huawei Tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue in this thread: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2963

It also points out that this issue might be on the android system side of things.

Short answer: Also add `ConfigChanges.Navigation` to the main activity